# Getting UI display related data from the API

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, architecture, software-design

From a best practice point of view, is it considered ok to get things like friendly names aka descriptions that you need to display on the UI from your API? Or should the API be oblivious of how the data is shown to the user?

Comment: what other method you have instead of getting user data from api?

Comment: having a map between the api naming and the UI one in the Angular app. But the problem with this is that I need to switch back and forth when filtering or using them in any request to the api.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fine to get this from the API. Note that if you're supporting multiple languages you would need to either return multiple labels or add a language parameter to your API calls.

> having a map between the api naming and the UI one in the Angular app. But the problem with this is that I need to switch back and forth when filtering or using them in any request to the api.

I can see why using a bi-directional map doesn't feel right, and for this I would recommend that you deal with these fields as objects.  An object would have a canonical name which corresponds to the API schema (call this `slug`, `canonical`, `id`, `value`, etc.) and one or more UI labels (`label`, `title`, `translation`, `singular`, `plural`, `en`/`es`/`de`, etc.). In its simplest form:

```
interface Field {
    value: string;
    label: string;
}
```

When your app receives this `Field` object from the API, it should pass it around as a complete object.  UI components will display the label text by accessing specific property.  But they also have access to the whole object, so they can make an API request with the canonical value.